# In woocommerce, is there any way to empty wordpress default mini cart when order placed?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

In my site, when some user type place an order then I change their order status "processed" to "review". But when I'm doing that my mini cart is not empty.

So is there any to empty mini cart force fully for that perticular orders ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share some more details. Is the status change done from admin?

Comment: In my site only loged in user can placed order.

In my site, if User type A placed an order he can not pay untill order is not approved by Admin.
So what I have done is, when user type A placed order, I automatically chnaged order status 'processing' to 'pending' through coding. And not allow to pay for this order untill admin appove this order (Likes post comments in wordpress). When admin approve his order user get notification and he can pay for this order.

So problem is that, When user placed an order without payment, order is successfully placed. but mini cart not empty.